# Youtube api v3 - can't choose file to upload with python

Tags: python, youtube-api

I don't know nothing about python and I'm trying to upload a video to youtube.

I already got the code and I just need to say which file I want to upload in this line:

```
argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
```

Yet I don't know where to place my video name. For example: "video.mp4". I tried default="video.mp4", "video.mp4" after "--file", but I get this error:

```
argument --file is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a command line argument parser. So you add it as an argument while calling the python file.

like:

```
python uploadexample.py --file video.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an http 500 error when I try to upload :=(